# What's the most lightweight way to detect if browser is Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, browser, browser-detection

My boss wants our mobile web site to have a banner to prompt Android users to download the Android mobile app. So I am trying to figure out the most lightweight way to detect in Javascript if the user is coming in from an Android browser.

I've researched many other answers here on Stackoverflow that will help me to determine lots of info about the user's browser... but they all involve adding big hunks of code to my (already heavy) web site, and they are overkill. *I don't need to know browser capabilities, OS version, screen dimensions or anything else like that.* I just need the tiniest, simplest way to determine if the user is coming in on an Android browser. That's it. :-)

Comment: Inspect the user agent string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;

if(isAndroid) {
    // do something
}
```

Or, even shorter:

```
var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

The `i` modifier is used for case-insensitive matching.

Shorter technique taken from Cordova AdMob test project: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/00.-How-To-Use-with-PhoneGap-Build